# Require current password to set a new password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, grails-validation

I want users to input their current password when editing their profile.

This is how my user model looks like:

```
attr_accessor :current_password

def current_password
  errors[:current_password] << 'Incorrect password' unless self.current_password == self.password
end

validate :current_password, on: :update
```

And my controller params:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :name, :current_password, :password, :password_confirmation, :phone)
end
```

And the user form partial:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :password, "Current password" %>
  <%= f.password_field :current_password, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Current password" %>
</div>
```

But I get stack level too deep, it enters a validation loop.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method

```
def current_password
  errors[:current_password] << 'Incorrect password' unless self.current_password == self.password
end
```

calls itself: that's why you're getting the stack too deep error - it's stuck in a loop calling itself endlessly.

What you're attempting to do is confusing because the `current_password` method is overwriting the one created by `attr_accessor :current_password`, and actually doing some validation rather than just returning the value.  I would do this, instead:

```
attr_accessor :current_password

validate :current_password_same_as_password, on: :update

def current_password_same_as_password
  errors[:current_password] << 'Incorrect password' unless self.current_password == self.password
end
```

So, here, i'm leaving the attr_accessor methods alone: they are simple read-and-write into an instance variable methods.  The validation has a different method name so it's not fighting with the accessor method name.

Comment: Thanks, noob mistake.

Comment: Although the logic is not right, on the on: :update validation. self.current_password expects to be equal with the new password a users wants to set, so it will always fail.

Comment: That's true - if the profile editing includes changing the password, this won't work.  You'll need to think about how you handle that.

Comment: You could put the new password in an accessor, and then have a before_save callback to write this into the password field.

Answer (score 1):

current_password is calling itself. You have an infinite recursion.

You are basically doing this:

```
def current_password
  self.current_password
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others answers said you have an infinite loop in current_password. I would pull out the validation logic into its own method. Something like the following.

```
validate :has_correct_current_password, on: :update

def has_correct_current_password
  errors[:current_password] << 'Incorrect password' unless current_password == password
end
```